# BlackBerry Java sdk Installation on Linux

Tags: java, linux, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm new in BlackBerry development. I've used "blackberry native c/c++ sdk" for Blackberry app development but now I want to develop app in java language.Can anyone tell me the procedure how can I get "BlackBerry Java sdk" for Linux 32-bit?